# Using Biopython to find and extract FASTA matches to exact DNA sequence

Tags: python, biopython, fasta

I am trying to use Biopython to extract all of the DNA sequences from a FASTA file that contain a match with the following short DNA sequence: "GGCTCAACCCTGGA"

Here is what I have so far:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

source = "rep_set_no_spaces.fasta"
outfile = "rep_set_PNA_matches.fasta"
seq1 = "GGCTCAACCCTGGA"

# basically a function to check whether seq contains sub1
def seq_check(seq, seq1):
    return seq.find(seq1)

seqs = SeqIO.parse(source, 'fasta')
filtered = (seq for seq in seqs if seq_check(seq.seq, seq1))
SeqIO.write(filtered, outfile, 'fasta')
```

I am trying to adapt code from this post ([Filtering a FASTA file based on sequence with BioPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886170/filtering-a-fasta-file-based-on-sequence-with-biopython)), but my sequence of interest is neither at the start nor end of the sequence...

For example, here are some of my sequences... the 1st and 4th sequence match, but the 2nd and 3rd do not. I want to pull out sequences make a new fasta file with just those sequences that contain "GGCTCAACCCTGGA":

```
>110148arco.1D_184193
TACGGAGGGGGTTAGCGTTGTTCGGAATTACTGGGCGTAAAGCGCACGTAGGTGGATTGGAAAGTATGGGGTGAAATCCCAGGGCTCAACCCTGGAACTGCCTCATAAACTATCAGTCTAGAGTTCGAGAGAGGTGAGTGGAATTCCGAGTGTAGAGGTGAAATTCGTAGATATTCGGAGGAACACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGGCTCACTGGCTCGATACTGACACTGAGGTGCGAAAGTGTGGGGAGCAAACAGG
>110475arco.1D_40770
TACGGAGGGTGCGAGCGTTAATCGGAATTACTGGGCGTAAAGCGCGCGTAGGCGGTTTGTTAAGTCAGCTGTGAAAGCCCTGGGCTCAACCTGGGAATTGCAGTTGATACTGGCAAGCTGGAGTACGAGAGAGGGAGGTAGAATTCCATGTGTAGCGGTGAAATGCGTAGATATATGGAGGAATACCAGTGGCGAAGGCGGCCTCCTGGCTCGATACTGACGCTGAGGTGCGAAAGCGTGGGGAGCAAACAGG
>110484arco.1D_190999
TACGGAGGGTGCAAGCGTTAATCGGAATTACTGGGCGTAAAGCGCGCGTAGGCGGTTTGTTAAGTCAGCTGTGAAAGCCCTGGGCTCAACCTGGGAATTGCAGTTGATACTGATCGACTAGAGTACGAGAGAGGGAGGTAGAATTCCACGTGTAGCGGTGAAATGCGTAGATATGTGGAGGAATACCGGTGGCGAAGGCGGCCTCCTGGCTCGATACTGACGCTGAGGTGCGAAAGCGTGGGGAGCAAACAGG
>110525amin.3D_40107
TACGGAGGGGGCTAGCGTTGTTCGGAATTACTGGGCGTAAAGCGTACGTAGGCGGATTAGTAAGTAAGATGTGAAATCCCAGGGCTCAACCCTGGAACTGCATTTTAAACTGCTAGTCTAGAGTTATGGAGAGGTAAGTGGAATTCCTAGTGTAGAGGTGAAATTCGTAGATATTAGGAGGAACACCAGAGGCGAAGGCGACTTACTGGACATATACTGACGCTGAGGTACGAAAGTGTGGGTAGCAAACAGG
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this question is not about `Biopython` but about `Python`:

```
def seq_check(seq, seq1):
    if seq1 in seq:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

You can also put it directly into your generator expression:

```
filtered = (seq for seq in seqs if seq1 in seq)
```

Comment: Even more succinent: `def seq_check(seq, seq1): return seq1 in seq`

Comment: @Brooke_W If the answer solved your problem you should accept the answer